# Is there a dark mode browser extension that works in an opt-in way?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, firefox, dark-theme

Is there a dark mode browser extension that you can activate only in specific websites that are very hard to read without dark mode themes that they refuse to have?

Most dark mode extensions seem to do their job by default and then let you opt-out specific sites from running in their forced dark mode. I want the opposite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/)

It's available for both Firefox and Chrome

> Use **Invert listed only** if you wish Dark Reader to work only on listed websites.

https://darkreader.org/help/en/#site-list